# ¿Cómo establecer automáticamente un periodo de fechas con datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap, jsp

Tengo estos campos de fecha con la siguiente función:

```js
function validaFechas(){

 $('datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: false,
      defaultDate: new Date()
  
 });
 
 $('datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: false,
   defaultDate: new Date()
 });
    $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change",function (e){
      var fechaInicio = new Date(e.date);
      
   $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      var maximaFechaFin = new Date();
      maximaFechaFin.setMinutes(1);
      
   $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maximaFechaFin);
      });
 
     $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change",function (e)
    {
       
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
      var maximaFechaInicio = new Date();
      var minimoFechaInicio = new Date(maximaFechaInicio.getFullYear(), maximaFechaInicio.getMonth(), maximaFechaInicio.getDate() -92);
      
     $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minimoFechaInicio);
     });
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input id="fechInicio"  name="fechInicio" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
  <input id="fechFin"  name="fechFin" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Ambos deben de mostrar por default la fecha actual, su funcionalidad consiste en que si  por ejemplo selecciono la fecha 30/07/2018 en el `#datetimepicker2`,  entonces en el campo `#datetimepicker1` puedo seleccionar una fecha de máximo 3 meses atrás de la fecha que seleccione en el `#datetimepicker2`, es decir, puedo seleccionar hasta la fecha 30/04/2018, pero quiero que esa fecha máxima se muestre por default en el campo y si vuelvo a cambiar la fecha en el `#datetimepicker2` por 20/06/2018 se vuelva a actualizar el `#datetimepicker1` la fecha 20/03/2018,

Ahora solo me respeta el periodo de fechas que establezco, pero tengo que hacer manualmente el cambio de fecha ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se muestre automático?

Comment: Pasa lo mismo si cambias la fecha del picker 1?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer en el `onclose` del `datepicker`, que se llama cuando se cierra tras seleccionar una fecha:

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
   .....,
   onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
       var date2 = $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('getDate');
       date2.setDate(date2.getDate()-90); //Aqui modificas los días como quieras 
       $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker( "option", "minDate", date2);  
       //Si quieres darle un nuevo valor al datepicker
       $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", date2);
   }
});
```

Ten en cuenta que la fecha que le pones debe estar dentro del rango de fechas permitidas.