# ¿ como aplicar validaciones en datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo dos campos de fecha,

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input id="fechInicio"  name="fechInicio" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
  <input id="fechFin"  name="fechFin" class="form-control" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Al cargar la pagina El campo `fechInicio`muestra por default la fecha de 3 meses atrás de la fecha que esta seleccionada en el campo `fechFin`, por default el campo `fechFin` muestra la fecha actual, por ejemplo hoy 02/08/2018, entonces el campo `fechInicio` muestra  02/05/2018, y si muevo el campo `fechFin`, se actualiza el campo `fechInicio`,

Otra de las funciones que hace es que para el campo  `fechFin` no permite seleccionar una fecha mayor a la fecha actual, y el campo `fechInicio`, no permite seleccionar una fecha anterior a los 3 meses de la fecha fin, y tampoco permite seleccionar una fecha mayor a la fecha seleccionada en `fechFin`.

Hace las validaciones que menciono bien, pero las hace cuando primero doy click en el `"datetimepicker2"`, que es el campo `fechFin`, si yo aquí primero selecciono una fecha, actualiza la otra y aplica las validaciones, pero cuando yo entro a la pagina y quiero seleccionar una fecha del `"datetimepicker1"`, es decir la fecha inicio me deja seleccionar mas dias de la fecha de los 3 meses  y después en el otro campo, NO respeta las validaciones, porque me permite seleccionar una fecha mayor al del día actual en el campo fechFin`y no es correcto, solo lo hace cuando primero doy click en el`"datetimepicker2"`

Esta es mi función, como puedo hacer para que aplique las validaciones al yo seleccionar primero cualquiera de los campos?

```html
function validaFechas(){

 $('datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: false,
      defaultDate: new Date()
  
 });
 
 $('datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
   format: 'L',
   useCurrent: false,
   defaultDate: new Date()
 });
    $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change",function (e){
      var fechaInicio = new Date(e.date);
      
   $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      var maximaFechaFin = new Date();
      maximaFechaFin.setMinutes(1);
      
   $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maximaFechaFin);
      });
 
     $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change",function (e)
    {
       
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
      var maximaFechaInicio = new Date();
      var minimoFechaInicio = new Date(maximaFechaInicio.getFullYear(), maximaFechaInicio.getMonth(), maximaFechaInicio.getDate() -92);
      
     $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minimoFechaInicio);
     });
      
    }
```

Comment: Esto es una repetición del código de esta pregunta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185128/cómo-establecer-automáticamente-un-periodo-de-fechas-con-datetimepicker/185141#185141]? Lo que necesitas se puede hacer con las opciones minDate y maxDate del datepicker, las seteas al declararlo

Answer (score 0):

Si no puedes inicializar el constructor, como bien dijo carmen, podrías usar una suerte de wrap, y llamarlo desde el `window.onload`, asi los asocias desde un principio.

```
  function SetRuleDp2(p1, p2) {
   //Control dp2
    var date1 = $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker('getDate');   
    var maximaFechaFin = new Date();
    maximaFechaFin.setMinutes(1);

    $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maximaFechaFin);    
    $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(date1);
 } 
 function SetRuleDp1(p1, p2) {
   //Control dp1
     var date2 = $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker('getDate');
     var day2  = date1.getDate(); 
     var month2 = date.getMonth() + 1;              
     var year2 =  date.getFullYear();
     var maxFechaInicio = new Date(year2, month2, day2 - 92);
     $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(date2);
     $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(maxFechaInicio);
 }   
window.onload = function() {
     SetRuleDp1(); 
     SetRuleDp2(); 
 }  
 $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change",function (e){
     SetRuleDp1();      
 });
  $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change",function (e){
     SetRuleDp2();      
 });
```